# ECS System implementation, why iterate on registered entities instead of the continuous component array

Tags: paradigms, entity-component-system

A lot of the documentations i had read on the ecs system implementation seem to have a dynamic array that register the entities that the system want to interact with.

It's true that it's allow you to have easely the entities width multiple components, but don't that defy the whole purpose of having component manager holding your component in a continuous array to avoid the processor having to go to another zone of the memory on each iteration ?

Because now if we iterate on each entities of the dynamic array, even if the system only look for entities width one component, the processor still need to do back and forth between each entity, his component and the next iteration. Without speaking about system that pay attention to multiple components

Or maybe the processor is clever and will notice what we do and optimise it anyway ?